# React map() render items only with spesific key value

Tags: reactjs

How to map through the array and only render the  itmes where 'TopPicks' has the value of '1' ?

```
const Products = [
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'iphone',
    description: '....',
    image: '/assets/images/iphone.jpg',
    link: 'link',
    SubCategory: 'mobile',
    TopPicks: '1',
},
{
    _id: 2,
    name: 'samsung',
    description: ',,,,',
    image: '/assets/images/smasung.jpg',
    link: 'link',
    SubCategory: 'mobile',
    TopPicks: '2',
}
```

]

```
            <div className="product-list">
                {Products.map((product) => (
                    <Product product={product} />
                ))}
            </div>
```

Comment: use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `map`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter React Native Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132586/filter-react-native-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not related to `react` but to `js` code, you just filter the array using the chainable `filter` function from `js`

```
      <div className="product-list">
          {
            Products
              .filter(product => product.TopPicks == '1')
              .map((product) => (
                <Product product={product} />
              ))
          }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Question related to reactjs then my assumption is to use react ternary render

```
<div className="product-list">
    {Products.map((product) => (product.TopPicks === "1" ? <Product product={product} /> : null))}
</div>
```

P.S. if you have complex condition the best way is to filter the array before render